# Output to Log the output from CMD in SAS?

Tags: cmd, sas, checksum

I am trying to do a Check Sum on a file and I thought using the X command was a good idea.

```
x 'CertUtil -hashfile U:\Programs\test\example.xml MD5';
```

I have looked all over the web to find out if I can print the output from this to the SAS Log, or even better to ODS PDF, but can't find anything.

I did explore using the DM statement but again I am unsure whether I can use CMD with this.

How do I print the CMD output to the SAS Log?

> 

FINAL CODE AFTER ANSWER

```
filename fn pipe "CertUtil -hashfile U:\Programs\test\example.xml MD5";

data _NULL_;
infile fn MISSOVER DSD TRUNCOVER;
input 
VAR1 $200. ;
put _infile_;
IF _N_ = 2 THEN CALL SYMPUT("HASH",VAR1);
run;
ods pdf text = "CheckSum for example.xml: &HASH";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pipe` filename engine instead of an `x` statement:

```
filename fn pipe `CertUtil -hashfile U:\Programs\test\example.xml MD5';

data _null_;
infile fn;
input;
put _infile_;
run;
```

In the data step, the `infile` statement executes the system command, the `input` statement reads in the output of the command one line at a time and the `put _infile_` statement writes each line to the log.